# Can't install HP printer on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

When I use `hp-setup` to configure my printer HP-2546 on the wireless option, I click ***next***, select the printer and ***next*** again, then the following error message arise:

```
Please check the USB connection to your printer and try again. (Device I/O error)
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Quit `hp-setup`
2. `sudo apt remove ippusbxd`
3. Unplug and plug your printer on USB port
4. Launch `hp-setup` again